# What are the top Tier champions right now?

Tags: league-of-legends

Looking at the meta game or at tournament matches, what champions are considered **Top Tier** to you? It's anyone's opinion

Comment: Hi @Enix, your question was closed as not constructive because you're asking to solicit opinions, which is not the intention of this site. Those types of questions are better suited to a forum, We focus on Q&A where one best answer can be chosen for a question, which is not the case with yours. In addition, your question is too localized in time, and will quickly go out of date as the metagame changes. Our site tries to focus on questions that will stay relevant and accurate.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you like to play. I will list my top tiers for each role. no particular order of how good they are, just thrown together in my list.

- Jungle - Lee sin, Dr. Mundo, Shyvana, Maokai, Udyr, Shaco
- Top Lane - Vladamir, Rumble, Riven, Olaf, Warwick, Wukong, Gangplank, Kennen
- Mid Lane - Xerath, Ryze, Kennen, Karthus, Morde(if played correctly), Kassadin, Morgana, Sion, Twisted Fate, Ahri, Meh i throw Leblanc here too, shes crazy
- Bot AD - Corki, Kog Maw, Ezreal, Miss Fortune, Sivir
- Bot Support- Janna, Soraka, Nunu